# How to force user to not input Code in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I have a blog where i want to validate the Title field! The title field should only take digits (0-9) and letters (A-Z) and may be some special characters like (- or | ) BUT it should not accept code! I tried the below pattern but it is not working with me!

```html
<table>
    <tr>
       <td align="left"><b>Title :</b></td>
       <td align="left"><input type="text" name="title" class="inputw" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" title="Only digits and letters"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your regex only accepts letters and digits. Isn't this what you want? You can add `\|\-` to the string.

Comment: @Tvde1 but it isn't working! Please read carefully.

Comment: Remove the `^` from your pattern. That makes it exclude everything in it.

Comment: Thanks @Tvde1 (:

Comment: `[a-zA-Z\d |-]`, if you want to accept `_` as well you can simply use `[\w |-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you force it to start with a letter. Remove the `^` symbol